# Thymleaf switch statement with multiple case

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

**In Short**

I want to have switch statement in thymeleaf with logic once written to multiple case statements.

**In detail**

I want to implement this in the thymeleaf

```
switch(status.value){
  case 'COMPLETE':
  case 'INVALID':
     //print exam is not active
     break;
  case 'NEW':
     //print exam is new and active
     break;
}
```

My current thymleaf code which fails with runtime error

```
 <div th:switch="${status.value}">
      <div th:case="'COMPLETE','INVALID'">
         <!-- print object is not active -->
      </div>
      <div th:case="NEW'">
         <!-- print object is new and active -->
      </div>
 </div>
```

But the above code fails with error

> ```
> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Could not parse as expression: "'COMPLETE','INVALID'"...
> ```

**Note: I know the reason for this above error message. All I need is to know a way to implement switch with multiple cases for a single output**

Comment: There is no way to make it the way you want. Just use fragments in both cases if you wish to avoid code duplication, as pens-fan-69 stated.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

The failure is due to the fact that you don't have a valid expression in the first case.  Specifically,

```
'COMPLETE','INVALID'
```

is not a valid expression.  I suspect that what you are trying to do is include the div if the status is COMPLETE or INVALID. Unfortunately, I believe you will have to duplicate the markup for those conditions individually.  Let me suggest the following markup:

```html
<!-- th:block rather than unneeded div -->
<th:block th:switch="${status.value}">
    <div th:case="'COMPLETE'">
        <!-- print object is not active -->
    </div>
    <div th:case="'INVALID'">
        <!-- print object is not active -->
    </div>
    <div th:case="'NEW'">
        <!-- print object is new and active -->
    </div>
</th:block>
```

Alternatively you could resort to th:if which might actually work better in this case:

```html
<div th:if="${status.value} eq 'COMPLETE' or ${status.value} eq 'INVALID'">
    <!-- print object is not active -->
</div>
<div th:if="${status.value} eq 'NEW'">
    <!-- print object is new and active -->
</div>
```

Or even more simply:

```html
<div th:unless="${status.value} eq 'NEW'">
    <!-- print object is not active -->
</div>
<div th:if="${status.value} eq 'NEW'">
    <!-- print object is new and active -->
</div>
```

Comment: Yes I know it's not a valid expression. I posted to explain my need in specific. Thank you for your answer. Actually I'm currently using the `th:if` in my application.

Comment: Well, in that case I think you already have the best implementation.  Unfortunately there is no "fall through" for multiple cases in Thymeleaf like there is in Java unless you want to utilize the default case (which you could in this case, though it wouldn't improve the markup much over the if/unless). One option to reduce code duplication if you have many cases and want to use switch would be to use a fragment for the cases that should have the same markup.

Comment: There is also the possibility of a default case (which is almost a good idea for swtich/case, just put this at the end:

<div th:case="*">For all other (not defined) cases</div>

Comment: th:block with th:switch never worked for me.

I had to use div instead

Answer (score 7):

I hit the same issue today, where the object used in my `th:switch` is a Java enum. I eventually figured out that this was a Java equals() versus == issue. In the `th:switch` I have an enum object, but in my `th:case` I have a String object. I solved it by using a Thymeleaf string function to convert the enum object to a string, and then everything works.

```
  <div th:switch="${#strings.toString(datafile.status)}">
      <td th:case="'SUCCESS'" class="table-success">SUCCESS</td>
      <td th:case="'FAILED'" class="table-danger">FAILED</td>
      <!-- default case -->
      <td th:case="*" th:text="${#strings.toString(datafile.status)}" class="table-secondary">xxx</td>
  </div>
```

In my example above I'm using the switch to conditionally apply a Bootstrap style to a table cell.

---

An alternate solution is to perform the logic in Java code and expose the output value as an object property, then just reference that property in the Thymeleaf template. Something like this:

```
public String getBootstrapTableRowClassForStatus() {
    Objects.requireNonNull(status);
    switch (status) {
        case SUCCESS:
            return "table-success";
        case FAILED:
            return "table-danger";
        case PROCESSING:
            return "table-info";
        default:
            return "table-secondary";
    }
}
```

and then I use Thymeleaf `th:class`:

```
<tr th:class="${datafile.bootstrapTableRowClassForStatus}">
```

On my page, this will apply a Bootstrap color style to my table row based on the value of my Status enum in the Java object.

Comment: This is the actual solution dealing with enums. Been struggling with that until I found your answer. Thank you Jim Tough

Answer (score 0):

As pens-fan-69 answered this type of switch

```
switch(status.value){
  case 'COMPLETE':
  case 'INVALID':
     break;
  case 'NEW':
     break;
}
```

can be only translated in Thymeleaf to following `switch` statement (if you want to keep `switch-case` syntax) and not reply it with `if-else`

```
<th:block th:switch="${status.value}">
    <div th:case="'COMPLETE'">
        <!-- print object is not active -->
    </div>
    <div th:case="'INVALID'">
        <!-- print object is not active -->
    </div>
    <div th:case="'NEW'">
        <!-- print object is new and active -->
    </div>
</th:block>
```

I was facing an issue that in such cases I had to duplicate a lot of HTML code (in this case for `COMPLETE` and `INVALID`). This can be mitigated by using `th:fragment` and reusing them like this:

```
<th:block th:fragment="complete-or-invalid-case">
  <!-- your HTML for complete or invalid case -->
</th:block>

<th:block th:fragment="new-case">
  <!-- your HTML for new case -->
</th:block>
```

Then in `switch` you can reuse these blocks which reduces code duplicity

```
<th:block th:switch="${status.value}">
    <div th:case="'COMPLETE'" th:include="this :: complete-or-invalid-case"></div>
    <div th:case="'INVALID'" th:include="this :: complete-or-invalid-case"></div>
    <div th:case="'NEW'" th:include="this :: new-case"></div>
</th:block>
```