# Thymeleaf switch case catches all cases

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I try to show different status depending on a field gallerypicture.status with thymeleaf

```
<tr th:each="image: ${galleryPictures}" class=".col-sm-7">
                                <td th:switch="${image.status}">
                                    <p th:case="'neverReviewed'">
                                        <div class="img-container" style="max-width: 50px" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" th:title="#{root.client.mitarbeiter.detectionTable.neverReviewed}">
                                            <img th:src="@{/img/Check_blue_icon.png}" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; object-fit: contain;">
                                        </div>
                                    </p>
                                    <p th:case="'partiallyReviewed'">
                                        <div class="img-container" style="max-width: 50px" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" th:title="#{root.client.mitarbeiter.detectionTable.partiallyReviewed}">
                                            <img th:src="@{/img/Check_orange_icon.png}" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; object-fit: contain;">
                                        </div>
                                    </p>
                                    <p th:case="'fullyReviewed'">
                                        <div class="img-container" style="max-width: 50px" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" th:title="#{root.client.mitarbeiter.detectionTable.fullyReviewed}">
                                            <img th:src="@{/img/Check_green_icon.png}" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; object-fit: contain;">
                                        </div>
                                    </p>
                                    <p th:case="'*'">
                                        <div class="img-container" style="max-width: 50px" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" th:title="#{root.client.mitarbeiter.detectionTable.neverReviewed}">
                                            <img th:src="@{/img/Check_blue_icon.png}" style="width: 50%; height: 50%; object-fit: contain;">
                                        </div>
                                    </p>
                                </td>
```

with galleryPicture.status defined as an enum as follows:

```
public enum GalleryImage_DetectionStatus {
    neverReviewed,
    partiallyReviewed,
    fullyReviewed;
}
```

But thymeleaf applies all 3 cases at once. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Note that the default case is `th:case="*"`, not `th:case="'*'"`.

Comment: Regarding the approach suggested by @rushitvaishnani: that should have worked. If you want to get your switch working, you can [edit] your question and show us your attempt for that approach. (But I understand you now have `if` statements working.) An alternative is to give values to all of your enums - `neverReviewed("neverReviewed")` (and add in the necessary field, constructor and getter to the enum) and then you _will_ be able to compare them to strings in Thymeleaf.

Answer (score 1):

The default case '*' should be in the end. Please see here [thymeleaf tutorial](https://www.javaguides.net/2020/06/thymeleaf-switch-case-example.html) Then it will catch only non-specific cases.

Comment: Thanks! But this catches still all other three cases.

Comment: Is type of image.status String or enumeration? Can you attach this class please?

Comment: Its an enum. I attached its definition.

Comment: Maybe need to convert th:switch="${#strings.toString(image.status)}" or something like that. See here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657648/thymleaf-switch-statement-with-multiple-case

Comment: Thanks again, but it didnt help... Could it be that I set my html structure wrong or that image container does not work as expected inside th:case?

Comment: I wish I could answer. Is thymeleaf enabled in this page in the first place? I mean: do constructions like th:each actually list all the images?
My point is: take a working example from some source for th:switch. Then you change it step by step, approaching your own code. On every step you check the regression, So you will spot the culprit place in the code.

Answer (score 1):

for matching enum with switch case:
th:case="${T(yourpackage.GalleryImage_DetectionStatus).neverReviewed}"

Comment: I did. The evaluation of ${image.status} gives for example neverReviewed which should trigger only the first case but triggers all of them.

Comment: To match with enum, use case condition like th:case="${T(<your package>.GalleryImage_DetectionStatus).neverReviewed}"

Comment: Well, thank you. This still does not work with th:switch but I just change to th:if now which works....